# How to add Transition between videos using AVMutableVideoComposition

Tags: ios

I have a problem adding transitions between videos.  I successfully merge two videos using AVMutableComposition.  I also see AVEditDemo sample.  How do I add transitions between videos?  Please provide me a way how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you mean "AVMutableComposition", not "AVMutbaleComposition".  I've edited your question to reflect this.

Comment: @aashu hello i have same problem if you solve this problem please give me some suggestion.. thanx